# Webdriver not finding xpath element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write some Selenium tests to test Pandora FMS using the Java implementation of the webdriver exported by the Selenium IDE.

The initial login part works just fine:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http://brmew.lab.brmew.es";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl + "/pandora_console/index.php");
driver.findElement(By.id("nick")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("nick")).sendKeys("my");
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("credentials");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit-login_button")).click();
```

Then, the problematic part, which is clicking a menu. I've tried to do the most simple approach:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='subViews']/li[4]/a/div")).click();
```

But it did not work, so I tried:

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@id='subViews']")));
myDynamicElement.click();
```

You can find the HTML I'm testing this with in [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/374770/artica/forum/pandora_html.html) (it's way too large to paste it here)

#### Hidden menu

[image: Hidden menu]

#### Shown menu

[image: Shown menu]

Comment: what error it is shown? ... or the element exist but not shown in ur screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any exception? It seems that the element submemu item you are trying to click is invisible. If it get displayed on main menu click or mouse over you need to do that before perform click action to the element. For Example:

```
//Click main menu to open submenu
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Views']/div")).click();

//now access submenu
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='subViews']/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Or alternately more preferable way is:

```
WebElement viewsMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Views']/div"));
viewsMenu.click();
//or mouse over 
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
action.moveToElement(viewsMenu).build().perform();

//now access submenu
viewsMenu.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='subViews']/li[4]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you, but does not work. It is in fact invisible, but it is present in the HTML when the page loads. I'm editing my original question with some screencaps.

Comment: What is the error you are getting, can you share error trace? Is it something element not clickable? If element present in DOM but not visible this kind of error occurs. For that you need to have first that element be visible and then click it. In your case as stated eralier you need to click/mouseover on main menu item to make that submenu item visible.

Comment: The stack trace is: `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Comment: I've discovered that, if I hover with the mouse in the firefox window through the menus and it becomes visible, __then__ it clicks on it and continue the tests! Is there a way to just click it?

Comment: The `ElementNotVisibleException` triggers in the `viewsMenu.click();`line.

Comment: With Selenium1 (AKA RC) it was possible to click invisible element but selenium2 (AKA webdriver) expects element must be clickable/visible for click. The alternate, not preferable, solution is you can click using js, 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Well, you got it there, Mr. @user861594 ! :) Thank you very much for the response. A question that comes to my head though, is, should I move to RC? What are the benefits of staying with Webdriver?

Comment: The Simplest answer to "move to RC" is "NO" (even if i am fan of RC) because it is deprecated long back.

Answer (score 0):

From ur given link, i can't find the monitoring > views > agent detail
But it seems that first u have to click on

```
monitoring and than wait
```

than click on

```
views and wait
```

than click on ur

```
agent detail
```

for mouse hover use the below code

```
//get element as ur wish by css or xpath or id
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ur locator"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.moveToElement(elem).perform();
makeWait(5);
```

than after showing the element, than again get next element and use the code for hover.

Comment: It's not _clicking_, it's hovering the mouse. Is there way to do that using webdriver?